# DataGrid changing background color changes multiple row color

Tags: c#, wpf, colors, datagrid

I am trying to change the Background color of `Row` or `Cells` of my `DataGrid`and I am getting some weird, for me, changes.
When I change the color of X `Row` or `Cell` another `Row`'s down my list will also change.
The `Rows` changing are not `Visible` unless I scroll down to them.
Here is my hardcoded example of the code.

```
DataGridRow? firstRow = sDataGrid.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromItem(sDataGrid.Items[i]) as DataGridRow;
if( firstRow != null )
{
    DataGridCell? firstColumnInFirstRow = sDataGrid.Columns[0].GetCellContent(firstRow).Parent as DataGridCell;
    if (firstColumnInFirstRow != null)
    {
        firstColumnInFirstRow.Background = Brushes.Green;
        //firstRow.Background = Brushes.Green;
    }
}
```

Here is an Image of the `DataGrid`

[image: DataGrid]

I tried changing both `Row` and `Cell` colors and had same results.

**Update**

I added a `Binding`. However the color wont change until it goes out of view and then back to view again.

```
<DataGrid.RowStyle>
    <Style TargetType="DataGridRow">
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="{Binding RowBackGroundColor}"/>
    </Style>
</DataGrid.RowStyle>
```

Call

```
itemlist[x].RowBackGroundColor = "Red";
```

Added `INotifyPropertyChanged`. Fixed it. Thank you all

Comment: What triggers the Colorchange? Is there a button thtas supposed to change the selected cell, or just the first one? Or is this triggered by some other event?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because of the [UI virtualization](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/wpf/advanced/optimizing-performance-controls?WT.mc_id=WD-MVP-5001077) that is enabled by default.

You should either disable it by setting the `VirtualizingPanel.IsVirtualizing` attached property of the `DataGrid` to `false` or better yet avoid setting properties of the visual containers directly and instead use data bindings and triggers in XAML to change the appearance of the cells conditionally.

Comment: That seems to solve the problem. Buttons are changing the color and I can't bind it as it doesn't depend on the Grid itself.
I could use bindings to be honest.
Thank you

Comment: Hey again, I added bindings but I seem to have a similar problem.
The color won't change unless it item is refreshed but getting out of view and then back to view.

Answer (score 1):

Ok so since I do not know when and how the Changes are supposed to happen, I can not give you a solution right now. I can however try to explain the issue.
Basically what happens is: Yes you change the Background of the row that is currently the first. But when you scroll down, the row object underlying that first row "disappears" and moves position and changes Data. I know it sounds weird but to help you understand you can try this:
Create a eventhandler to check if your row changes data

```
public void RowChangedData(object sender, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
{
    //do some debugging, so you can read e
}
```

And then attach that handler to you row

```
firstRow.DataContextChanged += RowChangedData;
```

When you scroll down, your breakpoint should be triggered, showing you that your row changed the item its attached to. As I said this isnt really a solution, and more of an explanation attemt. Be mindfull that this is simply how I understand it.

[image: Maybe this can help]

Comment: This is called [UI Virtualization](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/wpf/advanced/optimizing-performance-controls?view=netframeworkdesktop-4.8)

Comment: I added bindings but I seem to have a similar problem. The color won't change unless it item is refreshed by getting out of view and then back to view.